# While adding plugins to Cordova project: Meteor

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I am trying to integrate push notifications and used raix push package notifications for this,
As per the installation process, I need to run the following commands

```
$ meteor add raix:push 
$ meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-device@1.1.5 
$ meteor add cordova:phonegap-plugin-push@1.5.2
```

But these versions are causing some problems, Please check the attached screenshot
[image].

I tried with version meteor add cordova:phonegap-plugin-push@2.0.1 but it also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try running with sudo as its a permission error.
Also, you can create a cordova-plugins file in .meteor folder mentioning the plugins recquired with their version numbers to get rid of the warnings. Ex :

```
   cordova-plugin-camera@2.4.1
   cordova-plugin-device@1.1.6
```